# List received like object in a function

Tags: java, list, function, object

This feature may receive in the variable object 2 types of list types: `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`. I have this function:

```
private void isAList(Object example)
{
}
```

I can iterate of two ways:

> `isAList(new ArrayList<String>);`
>
> ```
> or
> ```
>
> `isAlist(new ArrayList<Integer>);`

I want to know if the first element of this List is a String or an Integer. How I can know which is the first element of this Object (always received a list). this is my code:

```
private void isAList(Object example)
{
    if (example != null && example instanceof List<?> && **FIRST_ELEMENT_OF_example??** instanceof String)
    {
        for (String cad : (List<String>)example)
        {
            XXXXXX MY CODE XXXXXX
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `!((List)example).isEmpty() && ((List)example).get(0) instanceof String` ?

Comment: @Berger You should insert a check if the list is empty before though, otherwhise you'll get a lovely `Exception`.

Comment: to be specific here, all elements in this arraylist will be string, i think you mean numeric or non-numeric value, you may want to use a regexp to validate that ?

Comment: @Seth : Sure I added a check now .

Comment: yes! Thank you very much!! This is my last code: if (example != null && !((List<?>)example).isEmpty() && ((List<?>)example).get(0) instanceof String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
private void isAList(Object example)
{
    if (example != null && !((List<?>)example).isEmpty() && ((List<?>)example).get(0) instanceof String)
    {
        for (String cad : (List<String>)example)
        {
            // YOUR CODE
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Already an accepted answer, but more can be done:

First:

```
private <T> void isAList(List<T> example)
{
    if (example.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    if (example.get(0) instanceof Integer) { // Not null (!!) and Integer
        // ...
    } else {
        // null or String
        List<String> list = Collections.checkedList(example, String.class);
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the use of [Collections.checkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList-java.util.List-java.lang.Class-).

```
List<String> list = Collections.checkedList(list, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
   private void isAList(Object example){
     if (example == null)
       //handle it, return....
     try {
       List<String> list = (List<String>) example;
       for (String cad : list){
          XXXXXX MY CODE XXXXXX
       }
     }
     catch (ClassCastException e){
       //handle exception
     }
   }
```

There is no need to do so many checks, by using a try-catch block you ensure that if everything goes as planned you will iterate through your list of strings.
If it doesn't, there are two possibilities: the object is not a list, or the objects inside the list are not strings, in both cases a ClassCastException should be thrown and by catching it you should be good.

Comment: this is not correct because I could receive two types of Lists (Integer or String), and you give 'one' to be of type String

Comment: Yes, true. You will then try to iterate through the list of something else as String, by basically casting it, so a ClassCastException is thrown anyway. This will only work in case of List<String> object, since it is forced to do so, or to break (controlled by the exception) anyway.